# Perform network task in context of Dispatcher.Main

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

according to help, long network tasks should be performed in the context of Dispatcher.IO.

But why couldn't use suspend function like get in Dispatcher.Main context? Thread itself isn't blocked, so do we expect any problem from code like:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val client = HttpClient(Android)
    var data: String = client.get('http://example.com')
}
```

assuming `get` is suspend function taking much time.

Thanks.

Comment: "Thread itself isn't blocked" -- depending on the implementation of `get()`, it could be blocking a thread. Just because a function has the `suspend` keyword does not mean that it does not block a thread.

Comment: Actually I'm talking about https://ktor.io/clients/index.html#concurrency


It says:

_Remember that requests are asynchronous, but when performing requests, the API suspends further requests and your function will be suspended until done._


I understand this in a way, that thread is not blocked. Correct?

Comment: Probably only if something inside of `get()` is switching to a different dispatcher. In the end, *some* thread has to be running the code that is doing the network I/O. Unless something else specifies otherwise, your code is setting that up to be the main application thread. Initially, that work might get suspended, and it is theoretically possible that `get()` is yielding time internally (e.g., via `delay()` calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right here. You can make that network request in `Dispatchers.Main`.

It seems to be a common misconception, that just because IO is being performed by a suspend function, you must call it in `Dispatchers.IO`, which is unnecessary (and can be expensive).

suspending functions by convention don't block the calling thread and internally blocks in `Dispatchers.IO` if need be.

Comment: so why IO is introducing if it unnecessary ?

Comment: You can use `Dispatchers.IO` if you have a non-suspend function that blocks.