# Why does the querySkuDetails need to run in IO context?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, play-billing-library

According to https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate the `billingClient.querySkuDetails` is called with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

```
fun querySkuDetails() {
    val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
    skuList.add("premium_upgrade")
    skuList.add("gas")
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(SkuType.INAPP)
    val skuDetailsResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        billingClient.querySkuDetails(params.build())
    }
    // Process the result.
}
```

I am curious which benefits it gives as `querySkuDetails` is already a suspending function. So what do i gain here.

I could write the same code with

```
val skuDetailsResult = coroutineScope {
        billingClient.querySkuDetails(params.build())
}
```

There is no more context and i don't know how to download the source code of the billing client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying method being called is `querySkuDetailsAsync` which takes a callback and performs the network request asynchronously.

You are correct that `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` is not needed there, it actually introduces unnecessary overhead.

Gotten from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62182736/6167844

> It seems to be a common misconception, that just because IO is being performed by a suspend function, you must call it in Dispatchers.IO, which is unnecessary (and can be expensive).
>
> suspending functions by convention don't block the calling thread and internally blocks in Dispatchers.IO if need be.