# Get data from room db using async & await

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, deferred

I am trying to get data from Room Database using `async & await` inside `Coroutine Scope` but getting problem while returning value.

Here is my code:

```
fun getUserFromDB():Profile {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        return profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PROFILE LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getUserProfile():Deferred<Profile>
```

Here I want to return userProfile from the method but I cannot do that inside scope and it will be null if I return from outside of `Coroutine scope`.

Note: **I am not following MVVM pattern here but doing a simple example.**

Comment: You simply can't, a non suspending function can never return asynchronously, you may need to make funtion suspend otherwise use runBlocking to blockingly return the result.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Can you elaborate?

Comment: The answers below explained it already :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here but I'll first address the main issue.

```kotlin
fun getUserFromDB() {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val userProfile = profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
    }
    return userProfile
}
```

In `getUserFromDB`, the `launch` executes asynchronously from `getUserFromDB` and will not complete before you return.

## To guarantee completion you have two options (if you want to use coroutines).

1. Mark `getUserFromDB` as a suspend function. (Highly recommended)

```kotlin
suspend fun getUserFromDB() {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    val userProfile = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
    }
    return userProfile
}
```

2. Use `runBlocking`.

```kotlin
fun getUserFromDB() {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    val userProfile = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
    }
    return userProfile
}
```

## Now the main issue is addressed. There are a couple things here that break conventions and guidelines.

1. `getUserProfile` should not return `Deferred<Profile>` (especially if it's already suspending), as this is an unsafe primitive to be passing around, it should just return `Profile`. This way you don't introduce unwanted concurrency by accident and you don't have to write `await()`.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM PROFILE LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getUserProfile(): Profile

fun getUserFromDB() {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val userProfile = profileDao.getUserProfile() /* .await() */
    }
    return userProfile
}
```

2. When using coroutines with Room, it executes blocking calls in a dedicated thread pool, so you do not have to use one (`Dispatchers.IO`), it is safe to call in the main thread/dispatcher. More info in this answer [Why does the querySkuDetails need to run in IO context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385658/why-does-the-queryskudetails-need-to-run-in-io-context/62389175#62389175) .

```kotlin
fun getUserFromDB() {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    CoroutineScope(/* Dispatchers.IO */).launch {
        val userProfile = profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
    }
    return userProfile
}
```

3. Last and the least, if you create a `CoroutineScope` without cancelling it later, you should just use `GlobalScope` to reduce the number of allocations. People say "Avoid using `GlobalScope`.", which is true but you should equally avoid creating `CoroutineScope`s without cancelling them (I'd argue it's even worse).

```kotlin
fun getUserFromDB() {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val userProfile = profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
    }
    return userProfile
}
```

## TL;DR

I've structured my answer so that you can apply each change independently when you are ready.
If you just want the sum of all the changes then here it is.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM PROFILE LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getUserProfile(): Profile

suspend fun getUserFromDB(): Profile {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    val userProfile = profileDao.getUserProfile()
    return userProfile
}
```

Happy coding. :)

Comment: How do I cancel Coroutine Scope when the work is done?

Comment: There is a `.cancel()` method on `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: Awesome and complete answer. Thanks @DominicFischer

Comment: Are you sure that await is available ?

Comment: It is a method defined on `Deferred`.

Comment: first of three examples, why you can define a variable `userProfile` in the coroutine and then return it, the `getUserFromDB()` function should not be able to use this `userProfile`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comments: a non suspending function can never return asynchronously. Use next approach to get `Profile` from DB:

```
suspend fun getUserFromDB(): Profile {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao()
    return profileDao.getUserProfile().await()
}
```

Use `CoroutineScope` with `Dispatchers.Main` context to launch a coroutine, get `Profile` and update UI:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val profile = getUserFromDB()
    updateUi(profile)
}
```

Or more concise, without using `getUserFromDB()` function:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val profile = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).getProfileDao().getUserProfile().await()
    updateUi(profile)
}
```

Comment: await will wait till task is completed ? After task is completed it returns result. Is this right?

Comment: Isn't the first approach you mentioned will run on main thread or Select Query will handle it in background?

Comment: the coroutine will run in the main thread, `getUserFromDB()` is a suspend function, it will suspend the coroutine without blocking the main thread. 'updateUi(profile)' will run in main thread.

Comment: @Sergey What should be the return type of getUserProfile() when using await?

Comment: @SumitShukla, it should be `Deferred<Profile>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return a `Profile` data type from your query by doing this in your DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PROFILE LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getUserProfile(): Profile
```

Don't worry about making the call on the Main thread since Room handles the query on a background thread.

Now depending on your arquitecture you can start a new coroutine with `launch` to call `getUserProfile` but since you said you're doing a simple example you can just call `getUserProfile` like this:

From an Activity:

```
fun myMethod() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this@MyActivity).getProfileDao()
    val profile = profileDao.getUserProfile()
    //Do something with profile here
}
```

From a Fragment:

```
fun myMethod() = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this@MyFragment.context).getProfileDao()
    val profile = profileDao.getUserProfile()
    //Do something with profile here
}
```

From a ViewModel:

```
fun myMethod() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val profileDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplication<Application>().applicationContext).getProfileDao()
    val profile = profileDao.getUserProfile()
    //Do something with profile here
}
```

Comment: Isn't the profile variable will be null as query will run in background thread.

Comment: @SumitShukla `getUserProfile()` is a suspending call and it will be resumed as soon as Room responds.

Comment: @SumitShukla what for? or how?